# ASP.NET Core 2, OData v4 Attribute Routing

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

Is it possible to achieve the below routes using the asp.net core 2, web api, odata v4.

- /odata/controller/Product/
- /odata/controller/Product/{param}/
- /odata/controller/Product/{param}/Users
- /odata/controller/Product/{param}/Companies
- /odata/controller/Product/Companies/{param}

By using the attribute routing, declaring functions and customizing routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long experiment using attribute routing, functions and actions, the above can be achieved using the OData functions.

Below is the code for it.

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

builder.EntitySet<Product>("Product");
builder.EntityType<Product>().Function("Users").Returns<Users>();
builder.EntityType<Product>().Function("Companies").Returns<Companies>();

app.UseMvc(routebuilder =>
{
     routebuilder.MapODataServiceRoute( "OData", "odata", GetEdmModel());
     routebuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
}
```

Refer the below for more understanding.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to achieve it using attribute routing alone too.

```
app.UseMvc(b =>
{
    b.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "api/v1", GetEdmModel());
});
```

In the controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing;

[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("content/{contentId}")]
public IActionResult Get(string contentId)
```